# Test that method has a default value for an argument with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I test that a method that takes an argument uses a default value if an argument is not provided?

**Example**

```ruby
# this method shouldn't error out
# if `Post.page_results` without a parameter
class Post
  def self.page_results(page=1)
    page_size = 10
    start = (page - 1) * page_size
    finish = start + page_size
    return Page.all[start..finish]
  end
end
```

How do I check in rspec that `page` equals `1` if `page_results` is called without argument?

Comment: did you find any of the answers helpful? If so, please mark it as accepted. Please let us know, if you miss something or anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Testing that the `page` param has the default value set, is most likely not what you should test. In most cases, it is better to test the behaviour instead of the implementation ([Talk from Sandy Metz about testing](https://youtu.be/URSWYvyc42M)). In your case, you should test if the expected set of `Pages` is returned, when `page_results` is called without params (default case).

Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
describe Post do
  describe ".page_results" do
    context "when Pages exist" do
      subject(:pages) { described_class.page_results(page) }

      let(:expected_pages_default) { expected_pages_page_1 }
      let(:expected_pages_page_1)  { Page.all[0..10] }
      let(:expected_pages_page_2)  { Page.all[10..20] }

      before do
        # Create Pages
      end

      context "when no page param is give " do
        # HINT: You need to redefine subject in this case. Setting page to nil would be wrong
        subject(:pages) { described_class.page_results }

        it { expect(pages).to eq expected_pages_default }
      end

      context "when the page param is 1" do
        let(:page) { 1 }

        it { expect(pages).to eq expected_pages_page_1 }
      end

      context "when the page param is 2" do
        let(:page) { 2 }

        it { expect(pages).to eq expected_pages_page_2 }
      end
    end

    context "when no Pages exist" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
describe Post do
  describe '#page_results' do
    let(:post) { create :post }

    context 'without arguments' do
      it { post.page_results.should eq 1 }
    end
  end
end
```

The `create :post` statement is how you would do it with [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). But you could of course mock or stub out your model.

**Update**

```
describe Post do
  describe '#page_results' do

    context 'without arguments' do
      it { Post.page_results.should eq 1 }
    end

    context 'with arguments' do
      it { Post.page_results('foo').should eq 'bar' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right.. I want to test that the value of `page` is 1 if an argument isn't supplied in the results. Also, `page_results` is a class method. Sorry about that, updating the question.

Comment: You can just check what the method returns with arguments and without. Updated my answer.

Comment: But who says that the method returns the value you want to test?

Answer (score -1):

I use before_validation to set defaults e.g

```
before_validation do
      self.some_attribute ||=a_default_value
end
```

That leaves open the possibility to override the default

```
SomeClassWithDefaultAttributes.create(some_attribute:a_non_default_value)
```

Keep in mind that if #before_validation returns false, then the validation will fail